# When running a python script from the console what is the difference between py vs python

Tags: python, shebang

I have been reading about python, and I have certain doubts when using the shebang line. When I run:

```
py file_name.py
```

It executes the script using the python version that I have indicated in the shebang line, but when I execute,

```
python file_name.py
```

The last version of Python is used instead of the one that I have specified. I would like to know the difference between using `python` and `py` when running a script from the command line. My shebang line was  `#! python3.4`

Does using either `python` or `py` have different implications or eventually both are the same?

Comment: `whereis py | xargs ls -a `

Comment: `python scriptname.py` means *"run `scriptname.py` using the interpreter that `python` starts"*. I've never used `py`, but another option is to set an explicit shebang (e.g. `#! /usr/bin/env python3`) and make the script executable, then you can run it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(This answer assumes you're using Windows, but I expect it mostly applies to other OSes too, modulo some details)</sub>

"python.exe" is the actual interpreter. You have one for each version of Python on your system. Which version gets executed when you run "python" on the command line, depends on your `PATH` environment variable and your current working directory.

"py.exe" is the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher). You probably only have one, even if you have multiple Python installs. Mine is in `C:\Windows`. It looks at the script, decides what version it's using, and delegates the actual execution to the proper interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

To see what version of Python are in use for each command, run these two commands:

```
python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
py -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
```

If both show the same version, then on your system they are both *currently* the same. **However, one or the other might be updated.** I personally recommend to rely on neither, and to call the Python version that you want explicitly in your scripts.

Comment: I have used that piece of code to check the version that is run, and that's the reason I have asked the question. When I use `py` the version that I had specified was used, but not when using `python`. I would like to know those small difference between both although at first glance both seem the same.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: I've addressed your comment in an edit.